# HTTP Service is not getting discovered in OpenNms for tomcat8.5 without SendResonPharse

Tags: opennms

HttpMonitor Config was working fine with tomcat7 and http service was getting detected however as we have updated to tomcat 8.5 http service is not getting discovered unless we set connector properties as sendReasonPhrase=true, the difference in the curl response is like below in compare to tomcat7 and tomcat 8.5 (withoutsend Reson Phrase parameter set)

[image]

[image]

tomcat7 gives ok in its header and tomcat8.5 does not.

however option for sendreson phase will be deprecated and removed from tomcat9 and even this option will not be available (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)

I am not sure why httpMonitor in openNms is not able to detect the http service even the snmpwalk output see port 80 available (both with and without send reason phrase)
[image]

in poller-configuration.xml looks like below for http

```
<service name="HTTP" interval="300000" user-defined="false" status="on">
 <parameter key="retry" value="1"/>
 <parameter key="timeout" value="3000"/>
 <parameter key="port" value="80"/>
 <parameter key="url" value="/"/>
 <parameter key="rrd-repository" value="/var/lib/opennms/rrd/response"/>
 <parameter key="rrd-base-name" value="http"/>
 <parameter key="ds-name" value="http"/>
 </service>
```

even we tried setting

```
<parameter key="response-text" value="~\bOK\b"/>
and 

<parameter key="response" value="200"/>
```

however it did not help, i guess above parameter play its role once service got discovered however the problem here the service is not getting discovered (unless SendReson pharse  is turn on )  it will only detect http service in tomcat 8.5 if we have sendreson phase turn on in connector definition inside server.xml

Kindly help to understand this behaviour here and possible solution for this without any change on client side.

openNms version info:

[image]

Comment: when you say discover, you mean that you would like OpenNMS to find it automatically right? Have you ever tried via manual provisioning? What i mean is to force OpenNMS to look for that service on the node you want.

Comment: Yes I meant for openNms to discover it automatically, Yes I tried manually provisioning. and the provisiond logs says it can not find http service on that node untill I set sendResonPharse in tomcat true. it looks like the the http detector look for a particular response which does not get unless I set sendResonPhrase

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with the version 16 of OpenNMS. Do you have the chance to do a test with the latest 22 version (just to see if it's a fixed bug or it's still present)?